# What happens when I copy an AWS EC2 Instance from one region to another?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloning

What exactly gets transferred when I copy an AWS EC2 Instance from one region to another?

1. Do all the packages installed using `yum` get transferred?
2. Are all the core packages (with my added content - e.g. special settings in php.ini etc) get transferred?
3. Are all the files getting transferred?
4. Are all the DBs (assuming I have MySQL installed directly on the server and not on a separate RDS instance) get transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly gets transferred when I copy an AWS EC2 Instance from one
>   region to another?

The entire EBS disk image gets transferred, if something was stored on that disk, it gets transferred.

To be clear, the answer to all of your questions is "yes".

Comment: Unless some of the data referenced was on a separate (attached) EBS volume...

Comment: Define "data referenced". Included scripts?

Comment: @womble When you create the AMI, you can specify that any other attached EBS vols are included.

Comment: @TomGranot-Scalosub You're thinking about this *way* too much. **If it was stored on your server's root EBS volume or other attached EBS volume, it will get copied.** (as long as you select the correct vols for inclusion when you create the AMI)